# Is there a better way to parse the output of a command that produces a string with multiple columns than using awk '{print substr($0, 68)}'?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, sh

I run a CLI command that outputs various database values.  One CLI command example is:

```
show attributes attr=0x1006e mh=0x12003ea | awk '{print substr($0, 68)}' | grep -v Value
```

The output looks like this:

```
Secure Domain
```

So this technique definitely works.

Without the awk command, and subsequent "grep -v Value" command the output looks like this:

```
Id    Name    Iid    Value
0x1006e Model_Name_Attr  Secure Domain
```

Where Id=0x1006e, Name=Model_Name_Attr, Iid=Blank column, Value=Secure Domain

The columns don't match up in this "stackoverflow" website.  sorry.

The awk command works because there are exactly 68 spaces until you reach the first word in the Value column, which is "Secure".

I can't use `awk 'NR==1 {next;}; {print $3}'` because the output will simply be the word "Secure".  The name has a space in between, and I need the entire Value of `Secure Domain`.

I tried various iterations of awk and cannot find a solution.

Comment: Do you have to use a command that produces free-format output like this? Is there an API you can call to get the value you want?

Comment: No.  This is what I can do, and the only thing I can do :-(

Comment: `gawk` or `perl` or `ruby` or `python` support fixed width fields. Might be better for you purpose.

Comment: @dawg I think he's trying to find an alternative to assuming a specific column number.

Comment: @Barmar: Reacting to the phrase *there are exactly 68 spaces until you reach the first word in the Value column, which is "Secure".*

Comment: @dawg I know. But he wants an alternative to having to use substr, which depends on that magic number 68.

Comment: What's your input field separator? One tab or multiple spaces?

Comment: The awk command that Barmar shared seems to be working.  I'm going to test it in another command.  THANKS.  I'll report back and let you know if this will work.

Comment: The output shown in the question doesn't have 68 characters before `Secure Domain`. Can you fix it to match your actual output?

Comment: THANK YOU BARMAR!  SUCCESS!  What can I read about to see how you did what you did?  Is this a substitution thing?  sed?

Comment: To answer your question Barmar regarding "the output shown doesn't have 68 characters before "Secure Domain".... very true on this post, but on my terminal it is exactly 68 characters.

Comment: The simple, obvious answer to the actual question in the title is `cut -c68-`

Comment: We can't help you come up with the "best" way to parse input given just 1 line of sample input. If you ask a new question with multiple lines of input and expected output, including cases where the `Iid` column has a value, the `Value` column has 1 or 3 or more fields, etc. and tell us if the fields are separated by blanks or tabs or are fixed-width then we can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the first two fields from the line, then print the rest of the line.

```
show attributes attr=0x1006e mh=0x12003ea | awk 'NR > 1 {$1 = $2 = ""; sub(/^ +/, ""); print}'
```

Comment: That would convert all other chains of white space in the input to singe blank chars which may not be desirable.

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU awk, we can define the width of the first field to be 67 and print the second field. We'll use some big number for the width of the 2nd field

```bash
$ cat attrs.file
Id                  Name                                  Iid      Value
0x1006e             Model_Name_Attr                                Secure Domain

$ cat attrs.file | gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS="67 1000" '{print $2}'
Value
Secure Domain

$ cat attrs.file | gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS="67 1000" 'NR > 1 {print $2}'
Secure Domain
```

Comment: FYI since gawk release 4.2 you can use `*` instead of picking an arbitrary large number like `1000` to mean "the rest of the record".

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can do

```
awk '/^0x1006e/ {print $3,$4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying `NF` by a boolean flag (`0/1`) is an easy way to filter out non-matching rows ::

```
gawk 'NF *= 1 < NF' FS='^0x1006e[ \t]+[^ \t]+[ \t]+' OFS=
```

---

```
Secure Domain
```

if you know the delimiters are a single tab (`\t`) each, then it's simpler :

---

```
mawk 'NF *= 1<NF' FS='^0x1006e\t[^ \t]+\t' OFS=
```